# X3D Seems To Only Run Through Half The Loop

Tags: x3d

I have a java program that outputs through JAXB an X3D file.  Here is the current output.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<X3D version="1.0" profile="Full">
    <head>
        <meta name="Sim3DAnimator" content="jaxbtext.x3d"/>
    </head>
    <Scene>
        <WorldInfo info="by Patrick R. Aquilone" title="Testing Simu 3D Animator"/>
        <DirectionalLight ambientIntensity="1.0" intensity="1.0"/>
        <Viewpoint orientation="0.0 0.0 0.0 90.0" position="0.0 10.0 100.0" description="SIM3D"/>
        <Transform>
            <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000" DEF="person">
                <Transform rotation="0 1 0 0.000000">
                    <Transform rotation="0 0 1 0.000000">
                        <Transform rotation="1 0 0 0.000000">
                            <Transform>
                                <MetadataString value="test"/>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="0.000000 25.200000 0.000000">
                                    <Shape>
                                        <Sphere radius="8.0"/>
                                        <Appearance>
                                            <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                        </Appearance>
                                    </Shape>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform rotation="0 0 1 1.570800" scale="1 1 1" translation="0.000000 13.200000 0.000000">
                                    <Shape>
                                        <Cylinder height="16.0" radius="1.0"/>
                                        <Appearance>
                                            <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                        </Appearance>
                                    </Shape>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="0.000000 13.200000 0.000000">
                                    <Shape>
                                        <Cylinder height="16.0" radius="1.0"/>
                                        <Appearance>
                                            <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                        </Appearance>
                                    </Shape>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="9.600000 3.000000 0.000000">
                                    <MetadataString value="test-right-arm"/>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Cylinder height="21.0" radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 -10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="-9.600000 3.000000 0.000000">
                                    <MetadataString value="test-left-arm"/>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Cylinder height="21.0" radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 -10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="5.000000 -24.000000 0.000000">
                                    <MetadataString value="test-right-leg"/>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Cylinder height="21.0" radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 -10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="-5.000000 -24.000000 0.000000">
                                    <MetadataString value="test-left-leg"/>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Cylinder height="21.0" radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 -10.500000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="2.5"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                </Transform>
                                <Transform scale="1 1 1" translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                    <MetadataString value="test-torso"/>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 12.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="5.0"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Cylinder height="24.0" radius="5.0"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                    <Transform translation="0.000000 -12.000000 0.000000">
                                        <Shape>
                                            <Appearance>
                                                <Material ambientIntensity="0.5" diffuseColor="0.500000 0.500000 0.500000"/>
                                            </Appearance>
                                            <Sphere radius="5.0"/>
                                        </Shape>
                                    </Transform>
                                </Transform>
                            </Transform>
                        </Transform>
                    </Transform>
                </Transform>
                <PositionInterpolator keyValue="   0   0   0  10   0   0  20   0   0  30   0   0  40   0   0  50   0   0  60   0   0  70   0   0  80   0   0  90   0   0 100   0   0  90   0   0  80   0   0  70   0   0  60   0   0  50   0   0  40   0   0  30   0   0  20   0   0  10   0   0" key="  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19" DEF="person-position"/>
                <TimeSensor cycleInterval="1.0" loop="true" DEF="person-time"/>
                <ROUTE fromNode="person-time" fromField="fraction_changed" toNode="person-position" toField="set_fraction"/>
                <ROUTE fromNode="person-position" fromField="value_changed" toNode="person" toField="set_translation"/>
            </Transform>
        </Transform>
    </Scene>
</X3D>
```

My problem is that you can see that the interpolation accounts for 20 points but when it runs it only runs through half of them and then snaps back to the beginning.  I don't understand why it stops at the 10th interval.  I know I missed something but what?

BTW, I am new so anything you see that I can fix, go ahead and let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**fraction_changed** outputs values between 0 and 1. The **key** of PositionInterpolator has integer values starting from 0 to 20. This means that only the first (0) and second (1) value will be active whenever the TimeSensor starts/ends. Basically your transform will be translated 5 times to (0,0,0) and 5 times to (10, 0, 0) alternatively.

To achieve what you want you have to change the array of keys to something like:
key [0 0.05 0.10 0.15 .... 0.95 1]

or route **person-time.time** to person-position.set_fraction. This will go through all the key values once.

It should work this way.